# Json Schema- Parsing error in Json.NET

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I am currently facing a problem in parsing my json schema with `Json.NET`. My schema is composed by an array, whose items can be of two different types, as described in the example below:

```
"Operations": {
        "type": "array",
        "id": "Operations",
        "required": true,
        "items": {
            "type": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Sale_ID": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "id": "Sale_ID",
                            "required": false
                        },
                  },
                    "additionalProperties": false
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Purchase_ID": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "id": "Purchase_ID",
                            "required": false
                        },
                  },
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
```

This schema was validated in multiple validators, always with success. I'm trying to parse it as a `JsonSchema`:

```
JsonSchema js = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaAsString);
```

However, I get a `JsonReaderException`:

> Exception JSON schema type string token, got StartObject

I'm guessing this happens because my item type is not a string. I would like to know if it is possible to define non-string types in `Json.NET`, or if this is a known issue/limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`Json.NET` does not support complex schemas in the `type` property.</s>

**Update:**

**[Json.NET Schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema)** now has full support for Draft 3 and Draft 4, which includes support for complex schemas in the type property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer James. Will it be supported in future releases?

Comment: No, the next version of the JSON schema spec will replace it with a different syntax. No idea when I'll look into it.

Comment: Hello James. I would like to know, if possible, when we can expect an update of the JSON.NET to support the V4 draft. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im working on a draft v4 reader, generator and validator, see https://github.com/rsuter/NJsonSchema (its not yet finished)